# React typescript conditional rendering typeof Date

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to adapt the example from MaterialUI Table Fixed header for my project. I have a Date field. That's the problem.

I get the error message:
TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'DateConstructor' have no overlap.

```
<TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.RECORDNO}>
    {columns.map((column) =>{
        const value = row[column.id];

        return(
            <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                {column.formatFld && typeof value === Date ? column.formatFld(value) : value}
                                     {/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error*/}
            </TableCell>
        );
    })}
</TableRow>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: always the value and Date comparison will be false isn't, so  always it will return the value

Comment: can you add the value in the code, so we can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `typeof` operator only tells apart primitive types (`string`, `number`, `bigint`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `undefined`, `object` and `function`). To check if a variable is an instance of a class use the `instanceof` operator.

```
<TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.RECORDNO}>
  {columns.map((column) => {
    const value = row[column.id];
  
    return (
      <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
        {column.formatFld && value instanceof Date ? column.formatFld(value) : value}
      </TableCell>
    );
  })}
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check whether a value is a date this way:

```
value = new Date()
console.log(typeof value) // "object"
```

do it like this:

```
console.log(value.constructor.name === "Date") // true
```

Comment: Many thanks,
now I understand why the message comes.
It is interesting that "value.constructor.name" always returns string.
The data is retrieved from the database via Axios get <T>.
In the interface there are two fields of the type Date.
I don't understand why value.constructor.name returns "string".

Therefore "value instanceof Date" does not work either.

Comment: Axios can't return a date, it's probably a unix timestamp or a date serialized in a different way. Can you post how does the value look like when printed?

Answer (score 0):

This is my interface and this is how the data is output.

```
export interface IAnwesenheit {
    DATUM: Date,
    NAMEN: string,
    VORNAME: string,
    FIRMA: string,
    PERSONALID: number,
    FIRMAID: number,
    STARTZEIT: Date,
    ENDEZEIT: Date,
    BARCODEIDENT: string,
    BAUSTELLE: string,
    BAUSTELLEID: number,
    RECORDNO: number,
}

BARCODEIDENT: "Z"
BAUSTELLE: "München"
BAUSTELLEID: 4
DATUM: "2017-06-12T00:00:00.000+02:00"
ENDEZEIT: "1899-12-30T18:09:19.000+01:00"
FIRMA: "XY GmbH"
FIRMAID: 3
NAMEN: "Firma 1"
PERSONALID: 7
RECORDNO: 1
STARTZEIT: "1899-12-30T07:15:07.000+01:00"
VORNAME: "Person"
```

Comment: you have to parse the date strings when you fetch the data, eg: `const datum = new Date(result.DATUM)`

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks,
I implemented it now and it works.

```
<TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.RECORDNO}>
    {columns.map((column) => {

        const value = row[column.id];

        return (
            <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                {column.formatFld && (value as Date) ? column.formatFld(new Date(value as Date)) : value}
            </TableCell>
        );
    })}
</TableRow>
```